# Php - Foreach Variable

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to assign a value to the values ​​in the foreach loop I've defined a variable for this, but it returns a null value when I print

```php
$authority = getWithResult('authorites', 'UserId', $id);
$sidebar = null;
foreach($authority as $yetki){
    $sidebar = getWithResult('sidebar', 'Id', $yetki->SidebarId);
}
print_r($sidebar);
```

output:
Array ( )

Comment: Are you sure `$authority` is not empty?

Comment: The code only works as described, if the last call to `getWithResult` returns an empty array.  You probably want to try the code posted by @soyab-badi to see whats actually going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below code, In your case $sidebar value always override

```
$authority = getWithResult('authorites', 'UserId', $id);
$sidebar = [];
foreach($authority as $yetki){
    $sidebar[] = getWithResult('sidebar', 'Id', $yetki->SidebarId);
}
print_r($sidebar);
```